# Cannot redirect to next page

Tags: android, android-manifest

Here is my `Home.java` code. It is not redirecting to next page, even if I change the intent to (home.this, MainActivity.class):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Home extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openMainActivity = new   Intent("com.droid.mine.MainActivity");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();}{
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity.java` code. I.e next page
I am getting the error as ClassCastException:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button log,sign;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.linktologin);
        log.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        sign.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.register:
            break;
        case R.id.linktologin:
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.droid.mine"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.droid.mine.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
04-21 15:59:07.156: I/ApplicationPackageManager(21341): cscCountry is not German : INS
04-21 15:59:07.273: D/dalvikvm(21341): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 78K, 47% free 2860K/5379K, external   408K/517K, paused 95ms
04-21 15:59:09.648: W/dalvikvm(21341): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x40018578)
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity  found to handle Intent { act=com.droid.mine.MainActivity }
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341):    at   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
04-21 15:59:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21341):    at com.droid.mine.Home$1.run(Home.java:21)
```

Here is my Register.java class

```
package com.droid.mine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Register extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button backlog,regg;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    backlog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginn);
    regg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    backlog.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick (View v)
{

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.loginn:
        break;
    case R.id.signup:
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setClass(Register.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        break;
    }
```

}
}

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: You are getting a `ClassCastException`? Please edit relevant logcat output into your question.

Comment: Where is Register Activity in your manifest?  i.setClass(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
        startActivity(i); - it means you want to start Register Activity... And you definetly should add implements OnClickListener

Comment: @Kolchuga Register Activity will starts after getting into the MainActivity but my app is not directing into next page itself.i.e to MainActivity

Comment: @XaverKapeller i have posted logcat error above

Comment: 1)You activity should implements OnCLickListener interface. 2) Change Intent("com.droid.mine.MainActivity"); to Intent(Home.this, MainActivity.class); Otherwise you should register broadcatreceiver to catch Intent("com.droid.mine.MainActivity")

Comment: You should create the `Intent` like this: `new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);`. You should never do it like this: `Intent("com.droid.mine.MainActivity")` if at all possible.

Comment: @Kolchuga in my next class i.e in MainiActivity am using clicking function but still my app is not redirecting into that class itself

Comment: @Adarsha A P Remove intent filter from MainActivity in manifest

Comment: @Kolchuga yup it is working now...thanks alott

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

Change where you intent with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Secondly**

Just update your manifest with this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.droid.mine.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.droid.mine.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
       <activity
        android:name="com.droid.mine.Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>     
</application>
```

**Use this as home activity**

```
package com.example.pms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {        
    /*
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        final SplashScreen mSplashScreen=this;
        /*
         * The thread to wait for splash screen events
         */
        mSplashThread =new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(3000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                finish();

                // Run next activity
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSplashThread.stop(); 
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        mSplashThread.start();   
    }
    /**
     * Processes splash screen touch events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {    
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: my app is force closing..am getting the first page even it waits for the sleep time after that it asks for force close

Comment: and now no need to change the intent

Comment: just use the classes i gave u

Comment: even getting the same problem.i think i have got problem with my eclipse.do you know how to rest to default my build path

Comment: did u change the name of your apk?

Comment: no i have'nt changed anything till now but few day back got problem with my build path unknowing i fixed it..after that am getting these errors..

Comment: ok, just make a  new project and copy ur classes and files to it

Comment: this will be much easier and better for u... just make a new project , it will take just 5 mins and your project will be ready. most probably u must have changed the default build path by mistake

Comment: done with that error now if i click on the button with the id in the class MainActivity.java above posted it is not redirecting to next page ieven i have made change in manifest

Comment: u want to redirect on button click?

Comment: ya...i declared everything in manifest i.e below to MainActivity i declared my Register class in manifest.but if i click linktologin button which is in the class MainActivity my app asking for froce close

Comment: ok... one question what do u want when u click linktologin button of yours

Comment: it has to go for my login page i.e Register.java class

Comment: i have peasted my Register.java class above

Comment: your manifest has been updated in the question itself.. you have not declared register class in manifest

Comment: additionally your method of defining on click listener is not correct

Comment: btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: If it doesnt work then remove com.droid.mine   use just .MainActivity and .Home and .Register

Comment: Happy to help. pls tick this as answer so that it can help others in future

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead

replace

```
 .MainActivity
```

with

```
com.droid.mine.MainActivity
```

while declaring in Manifest file.

```
//delay in ms
int DELAY = 1000;

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);                  
    }
}, DELAY);
```

Comment: replace com.droid.mine.MainActivity in place of .MainActivity while declaring in menifest...

Comment: please do change as I edited in my answer  n let me know.. It will solve your issue..

Comment: No @AdarshaAP in your menifext you have added <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> and I am saying to replace activity name with com.droid.mine.MainActivity

Comment: done with that error but now if i click on to a button in MainActivity class with the id:linktologin it is not going to the login page

Comment: Ya added..but still my app is asking for force closing

Comment: i have pasted my Register.java class above

Comment: check now i have pasted

Comment: yet to start database now.sure i will let you...;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Home extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        Thread splashTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int splashTimer = 0;
                    while (splashTimer < 2000) {
                        sleep(100);
                        splashTimer = splashTimer + 100;
                    }

                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(Home.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("asd","dasd");
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Edit: Replace your manifest file with this, now I hope it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.droid.mine"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.droid.mine.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.droid.mine.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>   
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: i actully got some problem with configuring build path.how to restore into default..??

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `MainActivity` and `Register` Activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Mainactivity" />
<activity android:name=".Register" />

log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
    });
}

sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
        startActivity(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: @Adarsha A P ActivityNotFound exception is there in your logat

Comment: ya getting that exception

Comment: till now i have created only this much code and now i registerd remaining one more class also but also getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change your Intent to:

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Home.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

and in manifest file use:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>   
    </application>

</manifest>
```