# this code cannot go to next page

Tags: java, android

I want go to next page(mainActivity).
I was able to sign up and send that information to the database.
But only the success message and the ok button come out.
Errors not come out.
plz check my code.

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.life.registeration;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AlertDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    TextView registerButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    final EditText idText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idText);
    final EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userID = idText.getText().toString();
            String userPassword = passwordText.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            dialog = builder.setMessage("login success.")
                                    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                                    .create();
                            dialog.show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            dialog = builder.setMessage("Please, check your id.")
                                    .setNegativeButton("retry", null)
                                    .create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userID, userPassword, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}

@Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(dialog != null){
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you sign up , you have to go to Sign in ? what are you meanong in your question

Comment: Did you add `MainActivity` to the project's manifest? Did you implement the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate(..)` method properly?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris The database already contains data(id and pw).

Comment: @trylimits maybe...nope

Comment: @trylimits I modified it and followed it.[link_by. tushar narang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195444/cannot-redirect-to-next-page?rq=1) / home -> loginActivity, add android:label

 / but, I', failed :(

Comment: wgat is the problem you are facing