# Can not go to the next page

Tags: java, android

I want go to next page(mainActivity). I was able to sign up and send that information to the database. But only the success message and the ok button come out. Errors not come out. plz check my code.

LogingActivity.java

```
package com.life.registeration;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        TextView registerButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        final EditText idText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idText);
        final EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String userID = idText.getText().toString();
                String userPassword = passwordText.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if(success){
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                dialog = builder.setMessage("Login success.")
                                        .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                                        .create();
                                dialog.show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                            else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                dialog = builder.setMessage("please, check your id.")
                                        .setNegativeButton("re try", null)
                                        .create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userID, userPassword, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(dialog != null){
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.life.registeration">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" /><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: So where exactly is the problem? Clicking the login button or register button>

Comment: @OBX When the login is successful, success is displayed and it does not go to next page.

Comment: what about the register button ? are you able to launch next activity when you click on it?

Comment: replace `LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);`   to `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @OBX register button is not problem. The register button is working properly and I have also joined, id and pw are in db.

Comment: @Redman I tried this yesterday. But it failed. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this code cannot go to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924215/this-code-cannot-go-to-next-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With answer of [Prerak Sola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4350275/prerak-sola) add your `Activity` on `Manifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

Use your `.setPositiveButton` properly , your `OK` click event is `null` - `.setPositiveButton("ok", null)`:

```
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);                  
            }

        }).create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. After clicking "OK" the lines below `dialog.show()` will be anyhow executed.

Comment: @PrerakSola, I agree but I'm pointing out the exact use of the dialog.

Comment: Yes, I got that angle.

Answer (score 1):

You have not registered your `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Add the line `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />` in the manifest file. So it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.life.registeration">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Happy to help ... :)

Comment: @PrerakSola, Thanks for pointing out the `Manifest.xml` error, Combined work. :P